# How to avoid UIImageView contained in the UITableViewCell being expanded?

Tags: iphone

How to avoid UIImageView contained in the UITableViewCell being expanded when each table view cell has different height? I am having variable height for each row depending on the length of text coming for UILabel. When height of a UITableViewCell increases,the image view`s image height also increases. How to keep image view`s frame constant?

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
       NSString *text = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if(text.length!=0)
        {    

        CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(212, LONG_MAX);

        CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

        CGFloat height = size.height;

      return (71.0 + height); //this gives the row height
        }
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MyXYZ *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyXYZ" owner:nil options:nil];
        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[MyXYZ class]]) {
                cell = (MyXYZ *)currentObject;
]                break;
            }
        }
    }  

 ((HJManagedImageV *)cell.myImageView).url = [NSURL URLWithString:myImageUrl]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `contentMode` property of your image view to appropriate value to disallow scaling of the image inside image view and do not care about image view itself being resized.

Comment: I have used various values for content mode viz. UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,UIViewContentModeCenter,UIViewContentModeTop....but nothing happens. Still the image view takes the increased height only.

Comment: Ok, maybe you post some code then? How do you create image view, what autoresizing masks you assign (or maybe you use auto layout), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom cell in which you can keep the frame of the `UIImageView` constant. This will help it to remain the same throughout the tableView cells even if you vary the height of various cells

Comment: To add..I am using a custom cell only in which frame of my image view is constant. To ensure that the image does not expand, I also reset the frame of the image view with the same previous constant frame in cell for row at index path.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

[cell.contentView addSubview:imageview];
```